# Error while installing rvm packages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

When am trying to install 'rvm install 1.9.2' am getting the following error.

```
 ruby-1.9.2-p320 - #removing src/ruby-1.9.2-p320..
 Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
 No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/12.04/i386/ruby-1.9.2-p320.
 It is not possible to build movable binaries for rubies 1.8-1.9.2, but you can do it        for your system only.
 Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
 Checking requirements for ubuntu.
 Requirements installation successful.
 Installing Ruby from source to: /home/lister/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
 ruby-1.9.2-p320 - #downloading ruby-1.9.2-p320, this may take a while depending on your connection...
 ruby-1.9.2-p320 - #extracting ruby-1.9.2-p320 to /home/lister/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p320...
 ruby-1.9.2-p320 - #applying patch /home/lister/.rvm/patches/ruby/GH-488.patch.
 ruby-1.9.2-p320 - #configuring.....................
 Error running './configure --prefix=/home/lister/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320 --disable-  install-doc --enable-shared',
 showing last 15 lines of /home/lister/.rvm/log/1395656752_ruby-1.9.2-p320/configure.log
 checking locale.h presence... yes
 checking for locale.h... yes
 checking sys/sendfile.h usability... yes
 checking sys/sendfile.h presence... yes
 checking for sys/sendfile.h... yes
 checking time.h usability... yes
 checking time.h presence... yes
 checking for time.h... yes
 checking for net/socket.h... (cached) no
 checking for sys/socket.h... (cached) yes
 checking size of rlim_t... 0
 checking for size_t... yes
 checking size of size_t... configure: error: in `/home/lister/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-  p320':
 **configure: error: cannot compute sizeof (size_t)**
 See `config.log' for more details
```

Comment: What operating system? Also, it may be helpful to post the config.log file to a gist and paste the link in your question (be sure to remove any info that may be sensitive (hostname, etc)).

Comment: We are using ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Were you ever able to get this sorted?

Answer (score 0):

First of all run `rvm requirements` and see if you have everything that is installed that you need...if not, install them and then retry.

Also, if you could post your config.log to a gist and post the link, that would likely provide helpful information in the event the above fix doesn't work.